# frontend-maven-plugin detects wrong architecture resulting in wrong node download url

Tags: node.js, angular, maven, plugins, frontend

The build on our Jenkins Linux Server fails because a wrong architecture is detected by the plugin.
It detects x86 instead of x64 and node does not provide x86 releases for linux anymore, so the download fails!

This the output generated by the plugin:

```
[INFO] Node v8.9.4 was installed, but we need version v10.8.0
[INFO] Installing node version v10.8.0
[INFO] Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v10.8.0/node-v10.8.0-linux-x86.tar.gz to /home/tadmin/.m2/repository/com/github/eirslett/node/10.8.0/node-10.8.0-linux-x86.tar.gz
```

resulting in a 404 error, since this release does not exist.
The server is running JDK 1.8 with this configuration:

```
java -XshowSettings:properties -version
    os.arch = amd64
    os.name = Linux
    os.version = 3.10.0-862.el7.x86_64
```

I checked the source code of the plugin for detecting architecture and could not find anything wrong:

```
enum Architecture { x86, x64, ppc64le, s390x, arm64;
    public static Architecture guess(){
        String arch = System.getProperty("os.arch");
        if (arch.equals("ppc64le")) {
            return ppc64le;
        } else if (arch.equals("aarch64")) {
            return arm64;
        } else if (arch.equals("s390x")) {
                return s390x;       
        } else {
            return arch.contains("64") ? x64 : x86;
        }
    }
}
```

On my windows machine, the architecture is detected correctly.

Maybe someone also had this issue and can help me out here?

Comment: Just reproduced a simple example locally (`amd64` Linux too), and the plugin downloads the right Node binary (`https://nodejs.org/dist/v10.8.0/node-v10.8.0-linux-x64.tar.gz`). I also checked the source code, it seems correct at first sight. Are you using a specific Jenkins configuration that overrides `os.arch` property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so after some more debugging hours, it turns out that our operations team had (for some reason) installed a different JDK on the machine which then was used during the builds.

After switching to the usual JDK this issue disappeared.